# FastCGI Cannot execute script while reading response header from upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, nginx-config, fastcgi

Basically I have FastCGI configured in NGINX to use it for taking screenshots of my streamings but it doesnt seem to work. Every time I send a request like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/thumbnail?test
```

I receive this error in my docker logs

```
172.18.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2024:00:25:44 +0000] "GET /thumbnail?test HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.36.1"
2024/01/21 00:25:44 [error] 21#21: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Cannot execute script (/usr/share/nginx/cgi-bin/thumbnail.cgi)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /thumbnail/?test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/thumbnail?test"
172.18.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2024:00:25:44 +0000] "GET /thumbnail/?test HTTP/1.1" 502 28 "http://localhost:8080/thumbnail?test" "PostmanRuntime/7.36.1"
```

This is my nging.conf file

```
events {}
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # puerto por defecto para rtmp

        application live {
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_path /tmp/hls;
            hls_fragment 5s; # default 5s
            hls_playlist_length 30s; # default 30s
            # para permitir CORS
            # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

            # authentication
            on_publish http://auth_server:8000/auth;
        }
    }
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            root /www;
        }

        location /hls {
            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                application/octet-stream ts;
            }
            root /tmp;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

            # para permitir CORS
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;

            # para permitir CORS
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location /thumbnail/ {
            gzip off;
            root /usr/share/nginx;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/cgi-bin/thumbnail.cgi;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
            fastcgi_index thumbnail.cgi;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        }

    }
}
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM tiangolo/nginx-rtmp

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y fcgiwrap && \
    update-rc.d fcgiwrap defaults 20

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY index.html /www/
COPY thumbnail.cgi /usr/share/nginx/cgi-bin/thumbnail.cgi
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/cgi-bin/thumbnail.cgi

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

CMD /entrypoint.sh && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

And if it matters here is thumbnail.cgi

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
echo "Hello from thumbnail.cgi script"

STREAM_NAME=$QUERY_STRING
FFMPEG_CMD="ffmpeg -i http://localhost:8080/hls/${STREAM_NAME}.m3u8 -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 /tmp/thumbnails/${STREAM_NAME}.png"

$FFMPEG_CMD

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><body><h2>Thumbnail generado para el stream ${STREAM_NAME}</h2></body></html>"
```

Thank in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Does your image actually contain GNU bash?  Images based on Alpine Linux often don't.  It doesn't look like you're using any bash features and you could probably change the "shebang" line to `#!/bin/sh`.  (Make sure you _always_ double-quote shell variables, lest this script enable a remote-code-execution attach.)

Comment: Yeah it does. I've manged to execute it by giving permissions manually but now I get this error.
172.18.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2024:20:17:27 +0000] "GET /thumbnail/?test HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "http://localhost:8080/thumbnail?test" "PostmanRuntime/7.36.1"
2024/01/20 20:17:27 [crit] 19#19: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /thumbnail/?test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/thumbnail?test"